# WPF - Displaying single alternating item of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**How can I implement the following requirements using XAML?**

**Requirements**

In would like to develop a GUI in that displays an announcement "ticker" with the following requirements:

- The viewmodel contains a list of announcements.
- Only one announcement should be displayed at a time.
- After *n* seconds the announcement text should be replaced by the next one
- At the end the cycle should start with the first item again.
- The text itself should not be continuously moving (scrolling) or otherwise animated.
- Ideally a slight animation should visualize the transition when switching to the next announcement.

**Simplified ViewModel**

```cs
class Announcement
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
}

class HomeViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Announcement> Announcements {get;}
}
```

**Considered Option1: Hardcoded in Viewmodel**

I considered the following implementation option:

- Adding another Property in the ViewModel `VisibleAnnouncement`
- Updating it regularly via Timer
- Binding a TextBlock directly to this property

However I consider this property as redundant and would like to reuse the existent collection and define the transitions directly in XAML as this is a specific for the given View. But I was not able to find any ressources on how to build this using XAML. The ticker components I found on the net usually used some kind of marquee text or continuous scrolling.

Comment: Think about why we call it a *view* model.

Comment: Fair point, so I assume you would suggest sticking to the initial approach by adding and updating a new Property on the viewModel. In this case how could I implement an animation in Xaml triggered by the OnPropertyChanged Event?

Comment: You could use an EventTrigger on the Binding.TargetUpdated event.

Comment: You have stuff in a view model.  You wish to display that stuff a certain way... that's presentation, the responsibility of the View.  The logic for this display is confined to a single control with special behaviors... that's why we have UserControls.  How you wish to present the stuff in the ViewModel goes into the UserControl's logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Considered Option1" is the right way to go. It's OK that ViewModels are redundant. You are working with references, so that are only 32/64 bit you're saving "redundant".

Another option would be to have some kind of counter at which position you are right now. But then you also need another get-property that returns Announcements.ElementAt(counter) so you can bind your View to your ViewModel. So that's really unnessesary.

You should be using Option 1.